# Passing a model to a redirected page in MVC 5 from service method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and MVC5 so please bear with me if this is relatively easy, I just couldn't find anything useable in my searching.

In my app I have a blogs page where users can search for and select blogs to view. When they select a blog to view, the form posts back and process the request which goes to my blog service which retrieves all the posts for that blog. The question is once i populate the viewmodel for the blog posts page, How do I send the populated viewmodel to the controller to redirect to the page?

When the user clicks the button to view a certain blog, the form submission calls the blog manager which calls this method.

```
 public void ViewBlogPosts(int blogId)
    {
        var mgr = new BlogManager();
        var bpvm = mgr.GetBlogPostVm(blogId);
        //redirect to blog post page, passing bpvm             
    }
```

The above calls this which returns the populated viewmodel for the view.

```
public BlogPostViewModel GetBlogPostVm(int blogId)
    {
        var mgr = new BlogManager();
        var blog = mgr.GetBlogById(blogId);
        var blogPostList = mgr.BlogPostsForBlog(blogId);
        blog.BlogPosts = blogPostList;
        var bpvm = new BlogPostViewModel { Blog = blog };

        return bpvm;
    }
```

So in my ViewBlogPosts method, how do I pass the bpvm to the blogposts view?

Comment: Not clear what your asking here. What are you `ActionResult` method(s) that generate the view

Comment: You don't need to redirect if you're not making changes with the POST action. You can just `return View(model)`. If you do need to pass data you'll need to use `TempData` or `Session` and recall it in the redirected GET action. For PRG I always refer to this https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/.